# ACS account migration production

Tags: azure, acs

I have a client who has developed Social Media (Facebook) Logon capability using the Access Control Service (ASP.NET).

This was setup using a developer account (namespace) and made it the whole way to Production using this develop a/c. My client now wants to migrate it to a corp account (credit card). I was wondering what was the easiest approach to do this in Azure?

They were hoping for zero down time, I did suggest configuring everything on the new a/c and then making the necessary web.config changes, they wanted to know if there was an easier approach?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't think of an easier way but changing the config settings (essentially setting a new "trust" from the app to the new ACS namespace: the "issuer" attribute in the WIF config section + the trusted issuers section).

You will have to make sure the new namespace is configured so it supplies the claims your app expects => all config elements in the namespace just be right (e.g. RP, Rules, IdPs, etc). Bu tI think you got that already.

Comment: Thanks Eugenio, I had hoped there might be a migration tool (outside of the V1 to V2) that would allow you to do this, looks like the manual approach is the way to go, maybe the product team can take the tooling feedback on ;) Cheers!